# How to create a Windows To Go that can be updated with OS updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, dism, windows-to-go

```
rem These commands copy the selected image file to
rem predefined hard disk partitions on a UEFI-based computer.

rem Usage:   ApplyImage WimFileName 
rem Example: ApplyImage E:\Images\ThinImage.wim

rem === Copy the image to the recovery image partition =======================
copy %1 F:\sources\install.wim

rem === Apply the image to the Windows partition =============================
dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:F:\sources\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\

rem === Copy the Windows RE Tools to the Windows RE Tools partition ==========
md T:\Recovery\WindowsRE
copy W:\windows\system32\recovery\winre.wim T:\Recovery\WindowsRE\winre.wim

rem === Copy boot files from the Windows partition to the System partition ===
bcdboot W:\Windows

rem === In the System partition, set the location of the Windows partition ===
W:\Windows\System32\reagentc /setosimage /path R: /target W:\Windows /index 1

rem === In the System partition, set the location of the WinRE tools =========
W:\Windows\System32\reagentc /setreimage /path T:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target W:\Windows
```

Taken from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825089.aspx and modified to my PC.

F:\ is the mounted Windows 10 Anniversary Edition ISO

The other drive letters were created using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825686.aspx

When I attempt to run this command **dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:F:\sources\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:**

I get a 1005 Error

> Error: 1005
>
> The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure
>   that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume
>   is not corrupted.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

The dism log file is below

---

```
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   PID=9312 TID=12912
> Scratch directory set to 'C:\Users\SHAYAA~1.SID\AppData\Local\Temp\'.
> - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   PID=9312 TID=12912 DismCore.dll version: 10.0.14393.0 -
> CDISMManager::FinalConstruct 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                
> DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   PID=9312 TID=12912
> Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism" -
> CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info         
> DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
> PID=9312 TID=12912 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger 2016-10-10 09:27:34,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming
> that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
> PID=9312 TID=12912 Finished initializing the Provider Map. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info         
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Getting Provider
> DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has previously
> been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
> PID=9312 TID=12912 Getting Provider DISMLogger -
> CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info             
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has previously
> been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Manager: PID=9312 TID=12912 Successfully created the local
> image session and provider store. -
> CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info       
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Getting Provider
> DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has previously
> been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM  
> DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session -----> 2016-10-10 09:27:34,
> Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info     
> DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.14393,
> Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=8 2016-10-10
> 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version:
> 10.0.14393.0 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: dism  /Apply-Image
> /ImageFile:install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\ 2016-10-10 09:27:34,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Getting the collection of providers from a local provider store type.
> - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\WimProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\WimProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\VHDProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\VHDProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\ImagingProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\ImagingProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\CompatProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\CompatProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\FfuProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Connecting to the
> provider located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\FfuProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has not
> previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Loading Provider from
> location C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\SiloedPackageProvider.dll -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Warning 
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Failed to Load the
> provider: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism\SiloedPackageProvider.dll. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e) 2016-10-10
> 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Got the collection of
> providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table. 2016-10-10
> 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the
> commands from provider: DISM Log Provider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info   
> DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider:
> FolderManager 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM  
> DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: WimManager
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
> Succesfully registered commands for the provider: WimManager.
> 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting
> to add the commands from provider: VHDManager 2016-10-10 09:27:34,
> Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands
> from provider: GenericImagingManager 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info        
> DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider:
> GenericImagingManager. 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM
> DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: Compatibility
> Manager 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
> Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Compatibility
> Manager. 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
> Attempting to add the commands from provider: FfuManager 2016-10-10
> 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312
> TID=12912 Getting Provider GenericImagingManager -
> CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info             
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has previously
> been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info    
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Getting Provider
> WimManager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Provider has previously
> been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Error   
> DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=9312 TID=12912
> onecore\base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\wimprovider\dll\wimmanager.cpp:1054
> - CWimManager::Apply(hr:0x800703ed) 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=9312 TID=12912
> onecore\base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\imagingprovider\dll\genericimagingmanager.cpp:2535
> - CGenericImagingManager::InternalCmdWimApply(hr:0x800703ed) 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Imaging
> Provider: PID=9312 TID=12912
> onecore\base\ntsetup\opktools\dism\providers\imagingprovider\dll\genericimagingmanager.cpp:535
> - CGenericImagingManager::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800703ed) 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has
> been closed. Reboot required=no. 2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info            
> DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-10-10 09:27:34, Info                  DISM  
> DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session -----> 2016-10-10 09:27:34,
> Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-10-10 09:27:35, Info     
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Found the OSServices. 
> Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect 2016-10-10 09:27:35, Info      
> DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912 Disconnecting Provider:
> FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
> 2016-10-10 09:27:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
> PID=9312 TID=12912 Disconnecting Provider: WimManager -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:35,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Disconnecting Provider: VHDManager -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:35,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Disconnecting Provider: GenericImagingManager -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:35,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Disconnecting Provider: Compatibility Manager -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:35,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Disconnecting Provider: FfuManager -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider 2016-10-10 09:27:35,
> Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9312 TID=12912
> Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. -
> CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

I am trying to create an external bootable WIndows 10 PC that can be updated with software updates. Using Windows To Go was great until we found out that it can't receive updates.

Comment: have you tried rufus? Does it work? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a Windows To Go drive. Select the ISO in Rufus and make sure you select `Windows To Go`

[image]

and click on `Start`. This creates a proper Windows To Go drive wich can be updated fine.